# Is there a way to change the suggested spelling options in Chrome?

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome

Although this probably seems insignificant, but when I'm typing I never use apostrophe's in compound words. It takes too long and ruins my flow, as I'm pretty dyslexic this can turn into a real nuisance when I'm writing quite a bit.

The particular word that has me writing this post is `don't`, I normally write it as `dont` and my mac auto-corrects to the correct grammar. But chrome obviously doesn't auto change it, but it also doesn't give me the correct option when I right click. Which means I have to physically go back fix them all, and this drives me nuts.

This seems like a pretty huge oversight as I can't imagine in a million years that a majority of the people who type `dont` actually meant `font` and not `don't`. As I grammar check this I realize `im` is also subject to this weirdness.

Is there anyway to alter the suggested spelling box to have the option I want? Or a way to make abbreviation shortcuts similar to the iphone. I'm using Windows 10, and the latest version of chrome `69.0.3497.100`

Edit: I meant contraction not compound word whoops

Comment: People are more likely to read your question/answer if you format it so it is not a [wall of text](https://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Wall_of_Text). Please read [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help) and [edit] your question to add paragraphs and bullet points ...

Comment: Have you looked at the Grammarly extension?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps.

1. Open the **Settings** of the Chrome.
2. Roll down and expand the **Advanced**.
3. Find **Accessibility**, and click **Add accessibility features**.
4. Search for **Grammarly for Chrome**, and add it.

You can see the following picture, when it thinks that you have spelled error, it will have a red line.

And when you put the mouse on it, it will pop up a window for the possible and correct vocabulary.

Finally, it will tell you how many possible mistakes you have.

[image]

Hope this can help you.